# Scipy.optimize.minimize giving error when passed a single parameter with args

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

Given the following values

```
a = 100.0
b = 50.0
c = 200.0
```

The following code works (it doesn't do anything interesting)

```
def excessRevenue1(taxH,blah1,blah2):
    return taxH**2 + blah1 + blah2
    print optimize.minimize( excessRevenue1,c,args=(a,b) ).x
```

But the following code produces error << TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple >>. But the only difference seems to be that I am passing just one argument instead of two.

```
def excessRevenue2(taxH,blah1):
    return taxH**2 + blah1
print optimize.minimize( excessRevenue2,c,args=(a) ).x
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now Python thinks the `args` argument is a float, not a tuple so you just have to add a comma.

```
print optimize.minimize( excessRevenue2,c,args=(a,)).x
```

So then, now the function would work as expected, i.e.:

```
from scipy import optimize

a = 100.0
b = 50.0
c = 199.9

def excessRevenue1(taxH,blah1,blah2):
    return taxH**2 + blah1 + blah2

def excessRevenue2(taxH,blah1):
    return taxH**2 + blah1

print optimize.minimize( excessRevenue2,c,args=(a,)).x
print optimize.minimize(excessRevenue1,c,args=(a,b)).x
```

Would return:

```
>>> print optimize.minimize( excessRevenue2,c,args=(a,)).x
[ -1.65480420e-07]
>>> print optimize.minimize(excessRevenue1,c,args=(a,b)).x
[ -1.65480420e-07]
```